# How to efficiently digitize a color scale?

Tags: algorithm, colors, computer-vision

In the context of a doppler signal analysis, the measured velocities are converted to a color scale such as below. I unfortunately have no direct access to the velocity values, so I will have to **digitize the color scale back to a 1-D numerical scale**. I get the images (such as the one below) in the form of a `Python Numpy.ndarray` through an analog signal S-video cable. Can anyone point me towards a suitable algorithm, please? Should I try to use a color histogram?

### additional info:

The color scale is symmetrical, so if the max velocity is `x`, the minimum will be `-x`.

### The color scale:

- red: maximum positive velocity (towards observer)
- black: velocity = 0
- blue: maximum negative velocity (away from observer)

[image: doppler color scale]

This scale will be used to analyze such images (using OpenCV):

[image: use example image]

Comment: If it's actually symmetrical, wouldn't it suffice to save the maximum? From that you get the minimum, and from the length of the interval you get the rate of change (if the scale is symmetrical, the rate of change should be 1/length). Maybe I misunderstood, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This color scale seems to be fairly simple to reproduce without need to use HSV or HSL.

Supposing `x` is a `float` and can range from `-1.0f` to `1.0f`:

```
r = std::max<int>(0, std::min<int>(255,  512 * x));
g = std::max<int>(0, std::min<int>(255,  512 * (std::abs<float>(x) - 0.5f)));
b = std::max<int>(0, std::min<int>(255, -512 * x));
```